# Create Button in Section for Footer and detect correct Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have an Section Footer with an Button in it, but i dont know how to detect which section footer is clicked in my TableView. I know i have to use something like "tag", but how?

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

self.footerHeartView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 60)];
[self.footerHeartView addSubview:viewFotter];

UIView *viewFotter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 60)];

self.heartButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 5, 70, 50)];
self.heartButton.tag = section;
self.heartButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.heartButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(heartClick:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[viewFotter addSubview:self.heartButton];


[viewFotter setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
return self.footerHeartView;
}


- (void)heartClick:(UIButton*)sender {
NSLog(@"CLICK");

[[GTAppController sharedInstance].api sendLike:1 itemId:[[self.newsList objectAtIndex:???????]objectForKey:@"testId"]];
```

}

Thanks for your Time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cast sender as a button and read tag:

```
- (void)heartClick:(UIButton*)sender {
NSLog(@"CLICK");
    UIButton* sectionButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    int section = sectionButton.tag;

[[GTAppController sharedInstance].api sendLike:1 itemId:[[self.newsList objectAtIndex:???????]objectForKey:@"testId"]];
}
```

Hope this help.